# How to Back Up Account in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, email

I have a Thunderbird account installed on windows pc, I am planning to use my new computer with Ubuntu. The problem is that I don't know how to back up my Thunderbird account, I might lost all the contacts and my folders created. I am using POP3. What should I do to back up my email account. Thank you in advance

Comment: Mozila wrote a [nice article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_from_Windows_to_Linux) about how to go from Windows to Linux

Answer (score 0):

Backup or copy the profile's directory to where you want to save it to (for backup) or where you want to copy it to for new usage.

You can find the exact profile folder by looking at your profiles.ini file.  It'll be the "Path=" parameter in the profiles.ini file.  Copy that folder to a new Thunderbird installation and edith the "profiles.ini" to point to it and you're all set with the same settings and content from your previous install.

On Windows 7 or Windows 10 you can find the profiles.ini file in `%appdata%/Thunderbird`.  Just type that in the Microsoft file browser.

On Ubuntu you will find the profiles.ini file in `~/.thunderbird`.  You can type that path into the Ubuntu file browser to get there.

Thunderbird has a special argument to assist in changing and editing the profile to use.  Run this at the command prompt to see the facility:

```
$ thunderbird -profilemanager
```